Android Studio is crashing on project opening in mac
Android studio is crashing when i open the project, following is the exception in the java plugin that i am getting on android studio
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Cannot init component state (componentName=ProjectJdkTable, componentClass=JavaAwareProjectJdkTableImpl) [Plugin: com.intellij.java]
at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:148)
at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.initComponent(ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.kt:46)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.initializeComponent$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:622)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.createAndInitialize(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:47)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:39)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:154)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.createInstance$lambda$1(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:133)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.Cancellation.computeInNonCancelableSection(Cancellation.java:99)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.createInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:132)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.access$createInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:19)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter$getInstanceAsync$2.invokeSuspend(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:181)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter$getInstanceAsync$2.invoke(BaseComponentAdapter.kt)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter$getInstanceAsync$2.invoke(BaseComponentAdapter.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:89)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:169)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceAsync(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:176)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getServiceAsyncIfDefined(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:686)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getServiceAsync(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:677)
at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$preloadCriticalServices$2$1.invokeSuspend(ApplicationLoader.kt:230)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)


java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid arguments id: 174 (parent id = 0); nameId: 0
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator.invokeAndWait(LaterInvocator.java:133)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:446)
at com.android.tools.idea.ui.ApplicationUtils.invokeWriteActionAndWait(ApplicationUtils.java:39)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.deprecated.InstallComponentsPath$SetPreference.apply(InstallComponentsPath.java:340)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.deprecated.InstallComponentsPath$SetPreference.apply(InstallComponentsPath.java:327)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation$FunctionWrapper.perform(InstallOperation.kt:147)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.kt:52)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.kt:127)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.kt:52)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.kt:125)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.kt:52)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.kt:125)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.kt:52)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.deprecated.InstallComponentsPath.runLongOperation(InstallComponentsPath.java:249)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.deprecated.ConsolidatedProgressStep.doLongRunningOperation(ConsolidatedProgressStep.java:78)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.deprecated.ConsolidatedProgressStep$1.run(ConsolidatedProgressStep.java:58)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.deprecated.FirstRunWizardHost$LongRunningOperationWrapper.run(FirstRunWizardHost.java:460)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:429)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:114)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsynchronously$6(CoreProgressManager.java:480)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:252)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:186)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$13(CoreProgressManager.java:604)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:679)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:603)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:173)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:252)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid arguments id: 174 (parent id = 0); nameId: 0
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.ChildInfoImpl.<init>(ChildInfoImpl.java:50)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSTreeAccessor.doLoadChildren(PersistentFSTreeAccessor.java:93)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.list(FSRecords.java:355)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.update(FSRecords.java:385)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.findChildInfo(PersistentFSImpl.java:462)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.findInPersistence(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:140)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.doFindChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:126)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.findChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:75)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.refreshAndFindChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:333)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.VfsImplUtil.refreshAndFindFileByPath(VfsImplUtil.java:116)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemBase.refreshAndFindFileByPath(LocalFileSystemBase.java:130)
at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.AndroidSdks.getPlatformFolder(AndroidSdks.java:421)
at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.AndroidSdks.getPlatformAndAddOnJars(AndroidSdks.java:390)
at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.AndroidSdks.getLibraryRootsForTarget(AndroidSdks.java:327)
at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.AndroidSdks.setUpSdkAndCommit(AndroidSdks.java:277)
at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.AndroidSdks.create(AndroidSdks.java:239)
at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.createAndroidSdkPerAndroidTarget(IdeSdks.java:473)
at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:412)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.deprecated.InstallComponentsPath$SetPreference.lambda$apply$0(InstallComponentsPath.java:341)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:956)
at com.android.tools.idea.ui.ApplicationUtils$1.run(ApplicationUtils.java:35)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:209)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:191)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:829)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$3.run(ApplicationImpl.java:454)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:101)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:79)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:122)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:41)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:667)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent$lambda$7(IdeEventQueue.kt:571)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.withoutImplicitRead(ApplicationImpl.java:1444)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:571)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:68)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:349)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:348)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:348)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:343)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:995)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:995)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$4(IdeEventQueue.kt:343)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:829)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:385)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Following are the steps that android studio is asking me when i open it






look at the solution below, maybe it will help you
there is a solution here
